# Propagated Async/Await Method Calls

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

So I have this method in my base controller:

```
protected async Task<KeyValuePair<bool, string>> ExecuteSimpleQuery(Func<Task<bool>> service)
{
    var success = false;
    var message = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        success = await service.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        message = exception.Message;
        success = false;
    }

    return new KeyValuePair<bool, string>(success, message);
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(RegisterDto register)
{
    var objectStore =
        await this.ExecuteSimpleQuery(async () => await this.securityService.LoginAsync(register.UserName, register.Password, true));

    if (objectStore.Key)
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Toolbox");
    }

    this.TempData["error"] = objectStore.Value;
    return this.View(register);
}
```

So what I'm passing through to `ExecuteSimpleQuery` is an `awaitable` method `LoginAsync`, I just want to make sure I'm properly awaiting the method.

My thought process is:

1. `LoginAsync` returns a `Task<bool>` therefore the `Func` has to return that.
2. When passing it, you can `await` it, so do.
3. Because the `Func` returns a `Task<bool>` inside `ExecuteSimpleQuery` you can `await` it there, so should
4. `ExecuteSimpleQuery` is awaiting a method, therefore has to have the `async` keyword and therefore has to return `Task<T>`.
5. The last point propagates to the `Login` action, that method returns `Task<T>` so it can be awaited, so should.

Am I even close?

Comment: Why so complicated? Who do you delegate login call to `ExecuteSimpleQuery`?

Comment: Using service based architecture I have a really consistent way of calling a service, so instead of having to write out the `try...catch` all the time, I write it once and handle the same every time. Just a lot easier and less tedious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work. It can be simplified a little bit:

```
async () => await this.securityService.LoginAsync(register.UserName, register.Password, true)
```

could be written as

```
() => this.securityService.LoginAsync(register.UserName, register.Password, true)
```

because LoginAsync already returns a `Task`. That said always awaiting tasks whenever you process them has a certain consistency to it. It isn't really harmful to wrap this task the way you did. I think both ways are reasonable.

If `LoginAsync` can not throw any exception (that you care about) you don't need the lambda at all. Exceptions are usually stored in the `Task` when you call an async method. You could directly pass a `Task` to `ExecuteSimpleQuery`. If `LoginAsync` does not adhere to this pattern you cannot do this because the exception would be triggered too early.

```
   var loginTask = securityService.LoginAsync(register.UserName, register.Password, true);
   var objectStore = await ExecuteSimpleQuery(loginTask);

protected async Task<KeyValuePair<bool, string>> ExecuteSimpleQuery(Task<bool> service)
{
    //...

    try
    {
        success = await service;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

You can test this by saying:

```
   var loginTask = Task.Run(() => { throw null; });
```

The `catch` will be hit.